# How to set another public key for EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, public-key

I would like to change my public key for all instances EC2 in AWS.

I still have the previous key. So far, I created a new public key, but I don't know how to attach the newest to all EC2 instances.

Is there any way to do that without losing any instance?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a *list of all running instances*. You may already have one, if not you can use something like this:

   ```
   aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[]|select(.State.Name=="running").PrivateIpAddress' > instances.txt
   ```
2. Copy the new SSH key to all your instances:

   ```
   for HOST in $(cat instances.txt); do
       ssh-copy-id -i {new-key}.pem ec2-user@${HOST}
   done
   ```
3. Test if your new key works and then you can remove the old one from `~ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` on each instance. Again this can be easily scripted with a loop over the `instances.txt` above.

Hope that helps :)